# How to autorun an application when the Phone is switched ON

Tags: android, android-activity, autorun

Can anyone please give me code or links or concept for running an android application on android device automatically.. whenever the device is switched on, application should start on its own, with out the interference of the user.

Thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare a broadcast listener that listens for RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

In your listener:

```
Intent myStarterIntent = new Intent(context, YOUR_CLASS_TO_START.class);
/* Set the Launch-Flag to the Intent. */
myStarterIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
myStarterIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
/* Send the Intent to the OS. */
context.startActivity(myStarterIntent);
```

another example using the above ideas: [auto start app](http://www.coderanch.com/t/433898/Android/Mobile/AutoStart-App-Device-BootUP)

Comment: If you are starting an activity, the above will work. For a service, you will have to call startService(). If you find it's not working you should connect the device up to a computer and watch the system logs. If there is a permission problem or something else blocking it, it will show up there.